# JavaScript redirect to another page when time reaches 5 minutes to top of hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect a user to another page when the time reaches 5 minutes to the top of the hour.

In 24 hour time that means I want the redirect to run on intervals like this...

- 11:55
- 12:55
- 13:55
- 14:55
- 15:55
- etc

So far all I can figure out is the "count down" style of JS redirection like this, but instead of that I need something that runs based on time (5 minutes to the top of the hour) not a count down.

`setTimeout("location.href = 'https://www.google.com';",1000);`

I have also tried this but nothing happened.

```
var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
if (mins == 55) {
   window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
}
```

Is this possible with JavaScript (or jQuery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout() happens after a specified amount of time, where you have it defined to fire after 1 second (1000 milliseconds = 1 second) and then it will stop, unless you trigger the timeout again.

One solution is to check the timeout every 1 second using setInterval, and as soon as the minutes reach 55 minutes, do the redirect. You could also change this to trigger less frequently, say every 15 or 30 seconds (15000, 30000).

```js
// function that triggers at the interval
function checkTimeout() {
var now = new Date();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  console.log(minutes);
  if (minutes >= 55) {
    location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  }
}

setInterval(checkTimeout, 1000); // check interval every 1 second
```

Answer (score 5):

You're close - you just need to calculate the time remaining from when the user loads the page. I would throw this in the document.ready callback if you're already using jQuery.

```js
  const interval = 55*60*1000 // 55 min in ms
  const msUntilNext = interval - new Date().getTime() % interval;
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
     location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  }, msUntilNext)
```

Comment: This is perhaps a better approach than my answer as it uses a single timeout instead of an interval, but, mine would still work.